# Code optimization YandereSim: What does "replace class variables with functions" mean?

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine

I just watched YandereDev's most recent video and one of the tasks regarding code optimization is called "replace class variables with functions" (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7wNpStFPA0 at 7:33). Can anyone make sense of that and tell me what kind of code optimization technique that is? To me this looks like replacing a hammer with an apple. I just don't see how these two can be interchangeable.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You should probably contact the person(s) who made that video/presentation and ask them. Especially since the terminology used looks weird/non-standard.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo_Revision1
{
   public string Blah;
}

class Foo_Revision2
{
   public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

It's not an optimization, but then lots of the stuff in his notes aren't optimizations.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but `public string Blah { get; set; }` is a property not a function. And AFAIK officially C# only refers to anonymous functions as such. It seems the person who made the video does not have the best grasp of proper C# terminology

Comment: @UnholySheep - a property is one or two functions.

Comment: I see, thanks for all your answers! Too bad the mods put it on hold, because I honestly thought I was missing general coding knowledge for not understanding that. But the Property answer looks plausible enough.